# Looking for a visualization tool for MILP problems

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I often find myself in the situation that I have a large MILP problem given as a .lp file and I am struggling to analyze it by just reading the file. I was wondering if there are any tools out there made for this very purpose? To be clear, I am not looking for any optimization algorithms being performed, just an easier way to view the problem.

If it was up to me, I would imagine displaying the rows of the problem in a table as sparse view, e.g.

Constraint1 | Var1: 0.05 | Var4: 1.4 | <= 13

Constraint2 | Var5: -2 | Var7: 3 | <= 8

Ideally with the option of display variable bounds and value types by clicking / mouseovering.

Comment: Off-topic: _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more / This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the constraint matrix using Matplotlib's [spy()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.spy.html) method. This will generate a visualization of all non-zero elements and can provide clues about the structure of the problem.

With Gurobi, you can get the constraint matrix with [model.getA()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_geta.html)

This technique is also used for the [MIPLIB](https://miplib.zib.de/) and its [problem visualizations](https://miplib.zib.de/instance_details_30n20b8.html#structure): [image]